# Android : I need to arrange the layout of my application

Tags: android, layout, webview

I made my first Android application using eclipse. Now I need to arrange the Layout because my layout now show the Google AdMob ads over the main content, over the WebView. Also, when I rotate the phone and it gets into Landscape mode, the AdMob ads are only on the half of the screen. How can I fix this and how can I make the Google AdMob to have its own space, just like the progressbar, not to be shown over the WebView. This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/web_view_progress_bar"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="15dip"
android:padding="2dip"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/colorprogress" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/splash_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/splash"
android:visibility="visible" />

<WebView android:id="@+id/web_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:visibility="gone" />

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ads:adUnitId="a1500108406597c"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"
   ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the `AdView` within the `RelativeLayout`, which will put it on top of the items in there.

You want to put it within the `LinearLayout` only; I've shown you what you have to do if you want it between the `ProgressBar` and `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/web_view_progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/colorprogress" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adUnitId="a1500108406597c"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:visibility="visible" />

        <WebView android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Of course, if you want it at the bottom instead, put it above the `</LinearLayout>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I put the admob code above the </LinearLayout> but now the ads won't show up. I don't know where is the problem!?

Comment: It could be that the `fill_parent` of the `RelativeLayout`'s height is interfering. You may have to set that to `0` and use `1` as a weight, instead.