# How to add multiple layouts to the activity

Tags: android, list, layout

I am new to android programming and while doing the project I got an issue. I need to add a number of linear layouts which will contain text and button. I wrote the code, but it simply puts one layout over the previous one. What should I change in the code for it to put layouts in a list.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sanzharaubakir on 01.08.16.
 */
public class Scanned extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scanned);
        Intent in = getIntent();
        int num = in.getIntExtra("n", 0);
        String [] s = in.getStringArrayExtra("arr");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < num; i++)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + s[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            str.add(s[i]);
        }
        final List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0 ;i < num; i++)
        {
            final LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            setContentView(l, lParam);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView v = new TextView(this);
            v.setText(s[i]);
            v.setLayoutParams(lpView);
            l.addView(v);

            Button delete = new Button(this);
            delete.setText("Delete");
            delete.setLayoutParams(lpView);
            l.addView(delete);

            final int finalI = i;
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    intList.add(finalI);
                    l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

and XML file looks just as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you make a sincere effort, you'll find that somebody might've already asked a similar question on SO and received an answer. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077928/android-i-need-to-arrange-the-layout-of-my-application

Comment: @steady_daddy that is not what I am looking for, but thank you

Comment: I'm not sure but don't you think setting linear layout width and height being set to match parent is causing overlapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are using `setContentView` which would set the activity layout as your newly created layout EACH TIME. To do what you are willing, set an id to your linearlayout in the `R.layout.scanned` xml file and add your other linearlayouts to this. Also, remove `setContentView` from your loop above. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

don't create the linearlayout  instance inside the forloop,

```
final List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
final LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        setContentView(l, lParam);
    for (int i = 0 ;i < num; i++)
    {

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TextView v = new TextView(this);
        v.setText(s[i]);
        v.setLayoutParams(lpView);
        l.addView(v);

        Button delete = new Button(this);
        delete.setText("Delete");
        delete.setLayoutParams(lpView);
        l.addView(delete);

        final int finalI = i;
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intList.add(finalI);
                l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am still having this problem, layout goes over another

Comment: i have tried my code, but i get the layout horizantally, like {textview1,button1}{textview2,button2} and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
  final List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        l.setLayoutParams(lParam);
        //setContentView(l, lParam);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TextView v = new TextView(this);
        //v.setText(s[i]);
        v.setLayoutParams(lpView);
        l.addView(v);

        Button delete = new Button(this);
        delete.setText("Delete");
        delete.setLayoutParams(lpView);
        l.addView(delete);

        final int finalI = i;
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intList.add(finalI);
                l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
    setContentView(l,lParam);
```

It will worked for me..!!